# Errors when creating a Scala project with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbteclipse

When I create a Scala project with sbt I get the following error:

`ERROR org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS - caught exception in FS.readPipe()
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\xyz")`....

Though it will create the project and the correct structure. But when I go into the new folder of the project and run the sbt command, this error occurs:

`Unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.1.0: not found`

I put the dependency `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")` in the file project/plugins.sbt.

**EDIT** When I put the plugins.sbt file into the ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/ folder, then I can start sbt from the project folder but it will throw an error when in sbt I type in the command `eclipse`, saying it wouldn't be a valid command.

I use JDK 1.8, sbt 0.13.16 and Scala IDE 4.7.0

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There is a file called build.properties (i.e. hello-world/project/build.properties) and in this file I had a this line: `sbt.version=1.00.00`. I changed this to `sbt.version=0.13.16` then everything worked. I hope this helps others with a similar problem.

Though it is still not clear why `sbt new scala/hello-world` creates the project with `sbt.version=1.00.00` by default. Especially when typing `sbt about` will output that the used version is 0.13.16.

**Edit:** It is choosing version 1.00.00 (even when you download the 0.13.16 installer) because this is the newest version, if you want to run an older (still supported) version you will have to change it in the above mentioned sbt file.